# Google Play Services location API usage limits

Tags: android, geolocation, android-geofence

If you're using the newer Android  Location API features like Geofences or ActivityUpdates via Google Play Services, are you subject to any usage limits?

I know there's limits like, e.g. registering 100 Geofences at a time, but beyond that any usage limits I can find, in terms of requests allowed per day, etc,  seem to refer to the Google Maps API, as opposed to the Location API.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on usage of `Location API`. Limit is applied on registering `Geofences` only.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/limits) link for **Usage Limits For GeoFence**

**Request Rate**
`One request every five seconds, shared across Collections / Geofences / Entities.`

**Global Limit**
`Maximum per account:
1000 Geofences
3 Collections per Geofence
3 Entities per Geofence
10 loops per polygon
100 vertices per loop`

Hope this help you...

Answer (score 0):

If you log into the [API console](https://console.developers.google.com/) for your app, on the left side you can click on "API".  There is a list of all the APIs and their usage limits.